# Cumulative sum equation using for loop

Tags: r, loops, cumsum, cumulative-sum

I don't have a lot of experience with R, but I want to put an equation that uses a cumulative sum into R-studio. The equation is part of a set of discrete time equations, that are all modeled via for loops. 
Basically, I want to model this, but in a more simple way:

```
Zsec1 = g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprim1

Zsec2 = g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprim1 + g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprim2

Zsec3 = g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprim1 + g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprim2 + g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprim3 
..etc
```

Based on what I could find online, I tried using a for loop like this:

```
for (t in Time) print(cumsum({gamma*((1+c4)/(r+c4))*Zprm[t]}))
```

however the cumsum code does not do anything, as i get the same result when I take it out.

and like this:

```
total=0

for (t in Time) print({total <- total + (gamma*((1+c4)/(r+c4))*Zprm[t])})
```

Is there anyone that could please help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Would this work ? `cumsum(g*(1+c/r+c)*Zprm[Time])`

Comment: In your code you're using `cumsum` on a single element at each iteration, so it's expected that it will do nothing.

Comment: Why don't you isolate the term g(1+c/r+c) right away in your equations? Wouldn't that make things easier?

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the answer of the first comment. I just find it more intuitive to isolate the factor before taking the cumsum.

```
g*(1+c/r+c)*cumsum(Zprm[1:Time])[Time]
```

Comment: It looks as if the equation should be `g*(1+c)/(r+c)...` based on the OP's own code

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I have made this code:

    for (t in Time) print({Zsec[t]=(gamma*((1+c4)/(r+c4))*cumsum(Zprm[t]))
  
}) 

With gamma = 0.5, c4 = 2, r = 3, Zprm1=1, Zprm2=2 etc. For some mock results. However the results I get are 0.3, 0.6, 0.9 etc. So it still does not take the cumulative sum of the previous results..

Comment: A more simple example: if my Zprm is 1-5 for t 1:5 respectively, and I use this code: for(t in Time) print({cumsum(Zprm[t])}) The result I get is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So the (cum)sum part does not work..

Comment: I your simple example, you have to replace cumsum(Zprm[t]) by cumsum(Zprm[1:t]). Otherwise you take the cumsum of only one value, which is the value itself.

Comment: I edited the answer taking the previous comment into account. Also, note that cumsum() returns a vector whose last entry is the cumulative sum of the entire vector. Therefore, I added "[Time]" at the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your response!! I tried this, but I get the warning message: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. Can this be because I created Zsec as an array?

    for (t in Time) print({Zsec[t]=(gamma*((1+c4)/(r+c4))*cumsum(Zprm[1:t])[Time])
})

Comment: At this point, it becomes a bit messy. Could you please edit your question so that it shows a working example, i.e. all variables defined?
I think the problem in your code is now that you access the vector "cumsum(Zprm[1:t])"  at index "Time" which is not possible for "t<Time" because the length of the vector is "t".

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
Zprm<-rep(0,Time+1)
for (t in 1:Time){
  Zprm[t+1]=(gamma*((1+c4)/(r+c4))*sum(Zprm))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, for the first line, I get the following error: > Zprm <- rep(0, Time+1)
Error in rep(0, Time + 1) : invalid 'times' argument